# How do I temporarily change a text color (and back) in a Flutter widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm looking for a solution to temporarily change the text color in a Text widget to red for 3 seconds.  I can currently animate it to red, but how do I change it to back to as it was after this duration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this...

```
import 'dart:async';
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SO(),
    );
  }
}
class SO extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SOState createState() => _SOState();
}

class _SOState extends State<SO> {
  static final orgColor = Colors.black;
  var currentColor  = orgColor;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(child: Text("this is colored",style: TextStyle(color: currentColor,fontSize: 40),)),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          currentColor = Colors.red;
        });
        Timer(Duration(seconds: 3),(){
          setState(() {
            currentColor = orgColor;
          });
        });
      },),
    );
  }
}
import 'dart:async';
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SO(),
    );
  }
}
class SO extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SOState createState() => _SOState();
}

class _SOState extends State<SO> {
  static final orgColor = Colors.red;
  var currentColor  = orgColor;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(child: Text("this is colored",style: TextStyle(color: currentColor,fontSize: 40),)),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          currentColor = Colors.blue;
        });
        Timer(Duration(seconds: 2),(){
          setState(() {
            currentColor = orgColor;
          });
        });
      },),
    );
  }
}
```

---

Basically setting a timer to wait for some time(2 seconds here) and then reset the state.